# What is wrong with this simple code?

Tags: c

I know this might be a simple error however i still cant figure out the error. I am getting

the pointer address instead of the value when i print out an integer number.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    char s1[100];

    int words,lines,chara = 0;


    FILE * fp;

    fp  = fopen("fox.txt","r");

    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("Can't open file");
    }
    else{
        while (fscanf(fp,"%s",s1) != EOF){

            words++;

        //  printf("%s",s1);
            }

    }
        printf("There are %d of words",words);
}
```

fox.txt

```
The quick 

brown fox
jumps over

the lazy 


dog
```

output :

```
There are 2665625 of words
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`words` isn't initialised so you start incrementing from an undefined value.

```
int words,lines,chara = 0;
```

sets `chara` to 0 but doesn't initialise the other variables.  If you want to initialise all 3, you'd need

```
int words = 0, lines = 0, chara = 0;
```

Comment: damn..how did i missed that ..shame on me

Answer (score 3):

```
int words,lines,chara = 0;
```

This line declares 3 variables but initializes only `chara`.

Later in the loop you begin incrementing `words` but it is not initialized yet. **It has an undefined value.**

You can correct it by doing simply :

```
int words = 0, lines = 0, chara = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed initializing `words` variable

`int words =0;`

Uninitialized variable will have garbage value.