# Counting variables have high initial values?

Tags: c++

I want to count the letters from this file, grade.txt:

```
ABADACAFABCDFFFACDCCBBACBACCCBBAAAAADBACAFFBBCCDAABBFFAACCBBAACCCCBB
```

Heres the code:

```
#include <iostream> /* include header file to do input and output */
#include <fstream> /* include the library so you can read/write files */
#include <iomanip> /* include the library that allows formatting */
using namespace std; /* allow operations from standard library */

int main (void)
{
    int a,b,c,d,f = 0; //count of each grade
    char x; //stores the grade being read

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("out.txt"); //output file


    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("grade.txt"); //read file w/ grades

    while(infile >> x) { //for every grade from file
                 switch(x) { 
                           case 'A': 
                                     a++; //increase the count for whichever grade is read
                                     break;

                           case 'B':
                                     b++;
                                     break;

                           case 'C':
                                     c++;
                                     break;

                           case 'D':
                                     d++;
                                     break;

                           case 'F':
                                     f++;
                                     break;

                           default:
                                   cout << "Invalid grade";
                           }         
                 }    

    outfile << "\nCounts of Each Letter Grade" << endl; //output results
    outfile << "A: " << a << " B: " << b << " C: " << c << " D: " << d << " F: " << f;
    cout << "A: " << a << " B: " << b << " C: " << c << " D: " << d << " F: " << f;

    system ("pause"); /* console window "wait"¦ */
    return 0;
} /* end of main function */
```

My output is as follows:

```
Counts of Each Letter Grade
A: 169 B: 2686848 C: 18 D: 5 F: 8
```

I cannot for the life of my figure out why 'a' and 'b' have such high counts. When I debug, they appear to start at extremely high values, and then run normally.

Comment: You're only initializing 'f' to 0, the rest of the values are uninitialized.

Comment: Enable more compiler warnings. Problem solved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is wrong with this simple code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239436/what-is-wrong-with-this-simple-code)

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
int a,b,c,d,f = 0;
```

is equivalent to

```
int a; 
int b; 
int c; 
int d; 
int f = 0;
```

In other words, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are uninitialized.

You can fix it by using

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, f = 0;
```

or

```
int a = 0; 
int b = 0; 
int c = 0; 
int d = 0; 
int f = 0;
```

Comment: Someone did not understand variable initialization and got burned, R Sahu clarified it nicely and the OP will never make that mistake again (hopefully) +3, he did explain himself.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
 int a,b,c,d,f = 0
```

you only set **f** to **0**. The other ones are not initialized to 0.

You could do one by one

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

etc.
```

or something like

```
 int a,b,c,d,f;

 a = b = c = d = f = 0;
```

or

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, f = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your variables if you want them to have a know "initial" value. I see you initialized `f` with `0`, you need to do the same with the other *counting* variables.

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, f = 0; //count of each grade
```